# In an RCT, does running OLS on $Y_i = \beta_0 + \tau D_i + \varepsilon_i$ and recovering $\tau$ recover ATE or ATT

Tags: regression, expected-value, experiment-design, treatment-effect

Let's say I run an RCT and then run OLS on $Y_i = \beta_0 + \tau D_i + \varepsilon_i$ where $D_i$ is a dummy variable indicating whether an individual $i$ received the treatment. If I were to take the expectation of $y_i$, would $\tau$ be the ATE or ATT?

I understand taking the expectation works as follows:

$\mathbb{E}[y_i | D_i = 1]=\beta_0 + \tau + \mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_i | D_i = 1]$

$\mathbb{E}[y_i | D_i = 0]=\beta_0 + \mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_i | D_i = 0]$

Subtract the two to arrive at:

$\mathbb{E}[y_i | D_i = 1] - \mathbb{E}[y_i | D_i = 0] = \tau + \mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_i | D_i = 1] - \mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_i | D_i = 0]$

where $\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_i | D_i = 1] - \mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_i | D_i = 0] = 0$ if there is no selection bias.

Thus, I understand the right-hand side of the equation, but am confused as to the interpretation of the left-hand side.

Is the left-hand side ATE or ATT or am I missing something entirely? Thank you.

Comment: There are additional assumptions involves in expressing observed data functionals as counterfactual data functionals. For example, if (a) the counterfactual $Y^*_0$ is independent of $D$ and (b) the observed response $Y = Y^*_0$ when $D=0$, then $E[Y^*_0] = E[Y^*_0 \mid D=0] = E[Y \mid D=0].$

Answer (score 0):

In an RCT, the ATT and ATE are equal, so the OLS estimator is consistent for both.

Define $\tau_{ATE} = E[Y^1] - E[Y^0]$ and $\tau_{ATT} = E[Y^1|D=1] - E[Y^0|D=1]$.

In an RCT, $Y^d \perp D, \forall d$.

Therefore, $E[Y^d|D=1] = E[Y^d]$, so $\tau_{ATE} = \tau_{ATT}$.